# When does $G\times G\times G$ admit a faithful group action on a set of size $|G|$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

[Edited due to [YCor](https://mathoverflow.net/users/14094/ycor)'s [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413109/when-does-g-times-g-times-g-admit-a-faithful-group-action-on-a-set-of-size-g#comment1058839_413109):]
Given a finite group $G$, under what conditions does $G\times G\times G$ (the direct product of three copies of $G$) admit a faithful group action on a set of size $|G|$? This is equivalent to an injective group homomorphism from $G\times G\times G$ to $S_{|G|}$.

For reference, for every group $G$ with a trivial center, $G\times G$ admits an easy faithful group action on $G$ by $(g_1, g_2): g \rightarrow g_1 g g_2^{-1}$.

Comment: A sufficient condition is that $G$ admits a faithful rep of dimension $\le |G|/3$. I guess this is often the case. (For abelian groups this might be true iff $G$ is not 2-elementary of order 2,4,8?)

Comment: Hm. I may need to change my question -- I don't think I actually want a faithful linear representation. I need a faithful group action on a set of size |G|.

Comment: OK, so my comment become: a sufficient condition is that $G$ admits a faithful action on a set of cardinal $|G|/3$.

Comment: And on the other hand, it's necessary that $n^3 | n!$, where $n = |G|$. This doesn't happen when $n = p$ or $n = 2p$, nor for $n = 8, 9$, but should be true otherwise if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Note that YCor's condition is satisfied whenever for any different $p,q$ with $p^a \mid |G|$ and $q^b\mid |G|$, $\frac{1}{p^a} + \frac{1}{q^b} \leq \frac{1}{3}$, simply take $G/P_p \amalg G/P_q$ for the corresponding Sylow subgroups. This leaves $p$-groups, groups of order $2p^k$, $3p^k$, $20$ or $36$.

Comment: @AchimKrause the group of order 35 also just misses your bound. And it is in fact a group without any such action if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Notice also that if $G$ does not satisfy YCor's condition, then whenever $p$ is an odd prime divisor of $|G|$, each subgroup of order $p$ of $G$ must be normal in $G$. Furthermore, a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ which is a $2$-group has order $2$ or $4$, and every subgroup of order $4$ of $G$ is either itself normal, or contains an element of order $2$ which is central in $G$.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16858/smallest-permutation-representation-of-a-finite-group .  In particular the Babai-Goodman-Pyber paper mentioned in Grochow's answer seems to settle the question unless there is a bounded index cyclic subgroup of prime power order.

Comment: @AchimKrause I think there are a few more cases one still has to consider: groups of order $6p^k$, groups of order $cp^k$ with $c|12$ and $p^k \leq 11$ coprime to $c$, and groups of order $cp^k$ with $c|60$ and $p^k \leq 7$ coprime to $c$.

Comment: If YCor's condition fails, then any two subgroups $H,K$ of $G$ with $1/|H|+1/|K| \leq 1/3$ must intersect non-trivially (and in fact the intersection must contain a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$), by Achim's argument.  This is extremely restrictive and should kill off almost all remaining cases.

Comment: In particular if $p > 5$ there cannot be two different subgroups of order $p$, so the Sylow $p$-subgroups are cyclic.

Comment: If $G$ is soluble (which seems very likely), you can use Hall $\pi$- and $\pi'$-subgroups instead of Sylow subgroups in Achim's argument, for any set of primes $\pi$. It follows that if $n = c p^k$ with $(c, p) = 1$ then $1/c + 1/p^k > 1/3$. I think this reduces the cases to $p^k, 2p^k, 3p^k, 20, 28, 30, 35, 36, 44$.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think it is possible to give a fairly precise description of the groups $G$ which fail to satisfy the condition given by @YCor in comments, with the  exception of the case that $G$ is a $2$-groups. I will say a few words later about the case that $G$ is a $2$-group, and I think understanding the exceptional $2$-groups is not completely intractable with some more work.
Of course, this also makes use of the comments of @AchimKrause above.

So now let $G$ be a finite group which has no faithful permutation action on a set of cardinality $\frac{|G|}{3}$ or less, and suppose further that $G$ is not a $2$-group.

As I noted in comments, every subgroup of $G$ of any odd prime order is normal, for otherwise $G$ has a faithful permutation action on $\frac{|G|}{p}$ points for some odd prime $p$. Furthermore, if $p$ is any prime greater than $5$, then $G$ has cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroups. For otherwise, $G$ has an elementary Abelian subgroup of order $p^{2}$, and $G$ contains distinct subgroups $Q$ and $P$ of order $p$, in which case $G$ has a faithful permutation action on $\frac{2|G|}{p}$ points.

Now we note that if $p_{1}, p_{2}, \ldots ,p_{k}$ are all the odd prime divisors of $|G|$, then $G$ has a (normal) subgroup, say $K$, of order $\prod_{i=1}^{k} p_{i}.$

Suppose then that $4$ divides $|G|.$ Let $S$ be a Sylow $2$ subgroup of $G$. Then $G$ has a faithful permutation action on $[G:K] + [G:S]$ points, so that
$|K| \leq 12$, and we also see that $|S| < 8$ if $|K| > 3$.

We conclude that if $4$ divides $|G|$, then $|G|$ has only two prime divisors,
since $|K| \in \{3,5,7,9,11 \}$. Hence $G$ is solvable (by Burnside's $p^{a}q^{b})$-theorem, which is probably overkill here, but saves time), since $|K|$ is divisible by every odd prime divisor of $|G|$.  Let $R$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ for the unique odd prime divisor of $|G|$. Then  $[G:S] + [G:R] > \frac{|G|}{3}$ so that $|R| \leq 11$.

Hence in the case that $4$ divides $|G|$ (and $G$ not a $2$-group),  we have $|G| \in \{20,28,36,44 \},$ or else $G$ has order $3 \times 2^{k}$ with $k \geq 2$.

Thus we  may suppose that $4$ does not divide $|G|$. Suppose first that $G$ has even order. Then since $G$ has a cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroup or order $2$, $G$ has a normal $2$-complement, that is, (in this case), a normal subgroup, say $H$, of index $2$. There can be at most one odd prime $p$ such that $G$ has a Sylow $p$-subgroup of order $7$ or more ( later note added  for clarity: otherwise if $P$ and $Q$ are Sylow subgroups for distinct odd primes, then $G$ has a faithful permutation representation of degree $[G:P] + [G:Q] \leq \frac{|G|}{3}$.).

Furthermore, from the discussions above, we know that if $|H|$ has two different odd prime divisors $p$ and $q$, then $G$ now has subgroups of order $2p$ and $2q$. In that case, if the Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ is not normal, then we obtain a
faithful permutation representation of degree $\frac{|G|}{2p} + \frac{|G|}{2q} \leq \frac{|G|}{3}.$ (Later note added for clarity: so, we have established that if $G$ is not isomorphic to a direct product $C_{2} \times H$, then $G$ is a isomorphic to a semidirect product of $H$ with $C_{2}$, with non-trivial action of $C_{2}$ on $H$, and that $H$ is a $p$-group for some odd prime $p$ in that case).

Hence we conclude that either $H$ is a $p$-group for some odd prime $p$, or that
$G =  S \times H$ where $|S| = 2$ and $|H|$ has at least two prime divisors. Let $p$ and $q$ be prime divisors of $|H|$. If $p \geq 7$, then we obtain a contradiction, since $G$ has a subgroup of order $2q \geq 6$ and a subgroup of order $p$.

Hence we now are left with the so far untreated cases $|H| \in \{ 45,75,15 \}.$ If $|H| = 45,$ then $G$ has subgroups of order $18$ and $5$, leading to a contradiction. If $|H| = 75,$ then $G$ has subgroups of order $6$ and $25$, leading to a contradiction.

Now we are left with the case $|H| = 15$, and $G$ cyclic of order $30$.

Hence we are now left with the case that $G$ has odd order. We could quote the Feit-Thompson odd order theorem which seems like overkill, but we can avoid that here.

Suppose that $G$ is not a $p$-group for any prime $p$. If $|G|$ has three or more prime divisors, then the hypotheses on $G$ force the prime divisors of $|G|$ to be $3$, $5$ and $7$. (Later edit: Better argument- since we know that $G$ has subgroups of order $7$ and $15$,  we have a contradiction- recall that we know that every subgroup of prime order is normal).

Hence we may suppose that $|G| = p^{a}q^{b}$ for distinct odd primes $p,q$. We have seen earlier that either $p^{a} \leq 5$ or $q^{b} \leq 5.$ If $p^{a} = 5$, then we obtain $q^{b} \in \{3,7 \}.$ If $p^{a} = 3$, then we can place no further restriction on $q^{b}.$

Later edit: Sean Eberhard's comment came in while I was writing this.

Later edit due to questions in comments: We are left with the following possibilities :

a) $G$ has odd order, and $|G| \in \{p^{k}, 3q^{k}, 35 \}$ where $p,q$ are odd primes and $q > 3.$ Furthermore $G$ is a direct product of a group of order $3$ with a cyclic $q$-group in the case that $3$ divides $|G|$ and $G$ is not a $3$-group.

b) $|G| = 2m$ for some odd integer $m$, and $G$ has a normal Sylow $2$-subgroup. Either $G$ is isomorphic to a direct product of a group of order $2$ with a $p$-group, where $p$ is an odd prime, or else $G$ is cyclic of order $30$.( Edit: in fact, $G$ cyclic of order $30$ is not exceptional- in that case, $G$ has three subgroups with trivial intersection, of order $6,10,15$, giving a faithful permutation representation of degree $5 + 3 + 2 = 10$).

c) $|G| = 2p^{k}$ for some odd prime, and $G$ is isomorphic to the semidirect product of a group of order $p^{k}$ with a group of automorphisms of order $2$ acting non-trivially on it. In fact, one can see in this case that the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ must be cyclic, since otherwise, there are two different (normal, as explained earlier) subgroups of order $p$, and then two different subgroups of order $2p \geq 6$, giving a faithful permutation representation of $G$ of degree $\frac{|G|}{2p} + \frac{|G|}{2p} = \frac{|G|}{p}$. Hence $G$ is a dihedral group in this case.  Note that these are genuine exceptions, since if $G$ is dihedral of order $2p^{k}$ for $p$ an odd prime, then the only subgroup of $G$ which does not contain the unique (normal) subgroup of order $p$ of $G$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$ of order $2$.

d) $|G| \in \{20,28, 36,44 \}.$ There are cyclic exceptions of each of these orders.

e) $|G| = 3 \times 2^{k}$ for some $k \geq 2$. There exceptional nilpotent subgroups of this type for every $k$ since if $G$ has cyclic or generalized quaternion Sylow $2$-subgroups, then every subgroup of $G$ of even order contains the unique involution of $G$.

f) $G$ is a $2$-group.

In all cases, for each odd prime $p$, every subgroup of $G$ of order $p$ is normal, and for each prime $ p > 5$ the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are cyclic (allowing the trivial group) .

In fact, following the discussion in comments below with Sean Eberhard, it is the case that the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are Abelian for all odd $p$, and Sean describes the possibilities for the odd Sylow $p$-subgroups in his answer about the Abelian case.

Comment: Are there exceptional $p$-groups for $p \in \{3, 5\}$ apart from cyclic groups, $C_3^2$, and $C_5^2$?

Comment: The arguments in Section 3 of this Babai-Goodman-Pyber paper https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927879308824639 should help treat the 2-group case, though I haven't checked the details.

Comment: Good point. As you said in your answer, groups of order $p$ must be normal. Since the automorphism group of a group of order $p$ has order $p-1$, they must in fact be central. So all elements of order $p$ are central. What about something like $C_9 \rtimes C_9$.

Comment: Well, $C_9 \rtimes C_9$ is not interesting, because the two $C_9$'s have trivial intersection so induce a faithful action on 18 points.

Comment: Let $G$ be an exceptional $p$-group with $p \in \{3, 5\}$. As discussed, all elements of order $p$ are central. Let $H, K$ be subgroups of $Z_2(G)$ of order $p^2$. If $H \cap K = 1$ then we get an action on $2n/p^2$ points. Otherwise, $|H \cap K| \geq p$. Let $h$ and $k$ be generators of $H$ and $K$ respectively such that $h^p k^p = 1$. Then $(hk)^p = h^p k^p [h,k]^{\binom{p}{2}} = [h,k]^{\binom{p}{2}}$, so $(hk / [h,k]^{-(p-1)/2})^p = 1$, so $hk \in Z(G)$. This shows that $Z_2(G)/Z(G)$ has at most one subgroup of order $p$, so it's cyclic, so it's trivial, so $G$ is abelian.

Comment: @SeanEberhard : I see that $Z_{2}(G)$ is Abelian from the argument above, but why does that imply that $G$ itself is Abelian (maybe I am just missing some point)?

Comment: You're right, that's a gap.

Comment: I think your argument can be amended to something which works. It took too long to write it as a comment.

Comment: It could be useful to update the answer to list all the remaining unresolved cases.  Leaving aside the abelian cases treated in Sean's answer, it seems from the above discussion that the only possible exceptional groups are 2-groups, or of order 12, 20, 24, 28, 36, 44, or of order $3p^k$ for some $p \geq 5$, but I am not 100% sure that this is the correct conclusion of all the above discussion.

Comment: I should have made explicit that there are indeed non-Abelian exceptional groups $G$ of all the orders $12,20,24,28, 36$  and $44$. For $q \in \{3,5,7,9,11 \}$, we take $G = \langle x,y : x^{q} = y^{4} = 1, y^{-1}xy = x^{-1} \rangle$. As mentioned in the post, we  take $G = C_{3} \times Q_{2^{k}}$ for a non-Abelian example of order $3 \times 2^{k}$ for each $k \geq 3$. We may also take $G = Q_{2^{k}}$ as a non-Abelian exception for each $k \geq 3$, and  $G$ a dihedral group of order $2p^{k}$ for each odd prime $p$ and each positive integer $k$ for a  non-Abelian exceptional example.

Answer (score 8):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer. I will determine all the abelian groups failing to act faithfully on at most $n/3$ points.

Suppose $G$ is abelian, say $G = C_{q_1} \times C_{q_2} \times \cdots \times C_{q_k}$, where $q_1, q_2, \dots$ are (not necessarily distinct) prime powers. Then the minimal faithful permutation action of $G$ has $q_1 + q_2 + \cdots + q_k$ points. For a proof see https://mathoverflow.net/a/409831/20598.

Hence $G$ does not act faithully on $|G|/3$ points iff
$$q_1 + \cdots + q_k > q_1 \cdots q_k / 3.$$
It is maybe easier to think of this as
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k q_i / (q_1 \cdots q_k) > 1/3 . $$
Each of the terms here is at most $1/2^{k-1}$, so $k / 2^{k-1} > 1/3$, so $k \leq 4$.
By further analyzing $k=1,2,3,4$ we find all the solutions (where $q_1 \leq \cdots \leq q_k$):
$$
(q_1),\\
(2, q_2),
(3, q_2),\\
(4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (4, 11),
(5, 5), (5, 7),\\
(2, 2, q_3) \qquad (2 \leq q_3 \leq 11),\\
(2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 4),
(2, 2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2, 3).
$$

Comment: Does this also solve the original question for abelian groups. Namely, is it true that no $G$ in this list is such that $G^3$ acts faithfully on $|G|$ elements? (It seems so but I haven't entirely checked)

Comment: @YCor Yes, because the claim that the minimal faithful action of $G$ has $m = q_1 + q_2 + \cdots + q_k$ points, applied to $G^3$, shows that the minimal faithful action of $G^3$ has $3m$ points.

Comment: As just observed by Geoff, I think the case $(2,3,5)$ should be deleted (it barely fails the strict inequality).

Comment: @TerryTao Thanks, you're right.

Comment: It may be useful to add that this list in fact includes all (nontrivial) abelian subgroups of all groups $G$ not acting faithfully on $|G|/3$ points. (Proof: Suppose $H \leq G$ has a faithful permutation action on $m$ points. Then the induced representation of $G$ is a faithful permutation action on $[G:H]m$ points.) This and a couple further arguments show that all exceptional $p$-groups for odd $p$ are abelian.

Comment: Also probably worth making explicit that the only non- cyclic exceptional groups of odd order are those of type $(5,5)$ and $(3,3^k)$.